# Is there a way to dynamically display an image or video in a table row based on it's format?

Tags: php, html

I want to have an image or video preview based on the src provided from the database and then have this preview displayed in the table. The code below is the full table:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Theme</th>
          <th>Visual Idea</th>
          <th>Caption</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Visual</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <?php
          $table  = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM content WHERE uidCompany='" . $_SESSION[ "userCid" ] . "' && postStatus='Active'");
          while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
      <tr id="<?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?>">
          <td width="100" data-target="themeContent"><?php echo $row['themeContent']; ?></td>
          <td width="300" data-target="visualIdeaContent"><?php echo $row['visualIdeaContent']; ?></td>
          <td width="600" data-target="captionContent"><?php echo $row['captionContent']; ?></td>
          <td width="100" data-target="dateContent"><?php echo $row['dateContent']; ?></td>
          <td><img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>" width="100" /></td>
      </tr>
      <?php }
          ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the  I want to dynamically change based on the file extension provided is:

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>" width="100"/></td>
```

I had a go at it myself by using strpos to check if $row['visualContent'] contained any of the extensions but as I'm not very experienced with this I haven't seen success. What I tried:

```
<?php
$image = "jpg jpeg png";
$video = $row['visualContent'];

   if( strpos( $image, $video ) !== false) {
   echo "<td><video width="200" height="200" controls>
   <source src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
   </video></td>";
   } else {
     echo "<td><img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>" width="100"/></td>";
     }
?>
```

I might be near a solution, or miles away, which is why I'm here to get guidance from the experts. Looking forward to your responses.

**UPDATE #1:**

I gave it another go and here is another version of the code that I produced. Still, it doesn't work but I feel a lot more confident that this code is closer to the correct syntax than the previous one I submitted.

```
<?php
  $video = "mp4";
  $table  = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM content WHERE uidCompany='" . $_SESSION[ "userCid" ] . "' && postStatus='Active'");
  while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
     <tr id="<?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?>">
         <td style = "display:none" data-target="uidContent"><?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?></td>
         <td width="100" data-target="themeContent"><?php echo $row['themeContent']; ?></td>
         <td width="300" data-target="visualIdeaContent"><?php echo $row['visualIdeaContent']; ?></td>
         <td width="600" data-target="captionContent"><?php echo $row['captionContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="100" data-target="dateContent"><?php echo $row['dateContent']; ?></td>
         <td><?php if( strpos( $video, '$row['uidContent'];' ) !== false ){
              echo '<video width="400" controls>
              <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>';
            } else {
            echo '<img src="<?php echo '$row['visualContent']'; ?>"width="100"/>';
            }
            ?></td>
```

Still waiting on any feedback I can get. Thanks.

Comment: You could, in theory, just use an [object tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object), which can used for pretty much any content type. It's not as "nice" as a video tag, though (there's no "fallback" option, like the source tags video supports, for including multiple encodings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close after Update #1! My English isn't very good, so I'm assuming you want to check if it's a video or an image and change the HTML tag output accordingly.

The syntax of strpos (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is `strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`.

Thus, by doing `strpos( $video, '$row['uidContent'];' )`, you are finding your src in 'mp4', which will always be false. Also, you don't need the quotes, echo & semicolon for `$row['uidContent']`, since you want to use it as a variable. It will be great to look up the basic syntax again :)

I saw that you have `$row['uidContent']` and `$row['visualContent']`. I'm assuming `visualContent` contains the media src, so I'm using it in my suggested answer. If I'm wrong, please update your question with example data for $row.

**Suggested code:**

```php
// refresher: $video = 'mp4';
<td><?php if( strpos( $row['visualContent'], $video) !== false ) {
              echo "<video width='400' controls>
              <source src='{$row['visualContent']}' type='video/mp4'>
              </video>";
          } else {
            echo "<img src='{$row['visualContent']}' width='100'/>";
          }
    ?></td>
```

Comment: Kyuriko, I just might name my firstborn child after you. Your suggestion worked to perfection! Thank you.